# Apple in-store configuration options (for a MacBook Air)

Tags: apple-store

Does someone know if the top 13" MB Air model (the one with 256GB SSD and a 1.8 i5 if I remember correctly) is physically sold (in Apple Stores) also with the RAM upgraded to 8 gigs? Or is **only** it an on-order option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple Retail stores carry the four "stock" configurations of MacBook Air, as well as what they call the "ultimate" model. The "ultimate model" is the 2.0GHz i7, 512SSD and 8GB RAM.

The model you desire (1.8GHz i5, 256SSD, 8GB RAM) is not sold in stores. You would have to choose between the "ultimate" model and the base configuration (which has 4GB RAM).

Comment: Mmmm, as I feared. I thought maybe since a 1.8GHz i5 + 256SSD + 8GB RAM is a pretty common configuration they would sell it.

Comment: You can order it online and choose "pickup in store" when you are on the shopping cart screen. This will cause them to build it and ship it to the store for you to pickup. Not instantaneous but still nice.

Comment: Is it faster than home delivery? As by now, it says it would be at my door between 03/21 and 03/25.

Comment: It's about the same speed. But it's safer for those who fear having packages left on their doorstep.